# PyAutoGui Locateonscreen (MAC and Windows)

Tags: python, opencv, ui-automation, pyautogui

Im facing some problems when i run my code.
Im developing the same code in Mac and in Windows.

The function LocateOnScreen from PyAutoGui is not working in Windows, even I installed OpenCV. The same image in MAC works perfetctly

I created a funtion to know if the code is running in Windows or Mac, just because the resolution

See the code below

```
    cond = True
    while cond:
        try:
            x, y = auto.center(auto.locateOnScreen(settings.btnLogin, confidence=.5))
            ## Click in Windows
            auto.click(x, y)

            ## Click in Mac
            auto.click(x/2, y/2)
            cond = False
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error", e)
    return
```

I just cant understand why it works in Mac and Windows keep returning None

[image: Login Button]
[image: Full page]

Anybody can help me?

Comment: "Not working" is not a helpful description.  What happens on Windows?  What does it return?

Comment: @TimRoberts it just return None

Comment: `None` means the button wasn't found.  Are you sure your `btnLogin` image exactly matches what's going to be presented on the screen?

Comment: @TimRoberts totally sure, and it works with no problems in Mac, im gonna edit the post with the images

Comment: "exactly" meaning it must be the exact scale, not scaled up/down at all

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the image size is different between Mac and Windows. The resolution and the size of the window are different. Should I minimize the image, or what should I do?

Comment: If the button gets resized or color corrected, then you have to look for the resized button.  You may need to do a screen grab on both systems and store two images.

Comment: you may have to investigate what "DPI" means to various systems, and how they scale GUIs -- if that game simply draws everything proportional to screen height (or width) you'll get all kinds of scales because everyone has a different screen. -- you'll have to figure out for this game specifically **what it does**

Comment: I find it strange that when he runs the code on Mac, every time he calls the locateOnScreen function it takes a screenshot and on Windows it doesn't.

Comment: @lucas antoni try to use the confidence parameter

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this:

1. Make sure your image is the same size as the one
   you're trying to find with your bot.
2. Put it in the same folder as the ".py" file as
   "btnLogin.jpg".

The **working** code should be like this:

```
import pyautogui
cond = True

while cond:
    try:
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('btnLogin.jpg')
        #Click in Windows
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        cond = False
    except Exception as Ex:
        print('Error: ', Ex)
```

This is basically the core of the code, doesn't cycle but should be fast enough if you just need to automate a login:

```
import pyautogui
try:
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('btnLogin.jpg')
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
except Exception as Ex:
    print('ERROR: ', Ex)
```

*Let me know if something isn't clear or doesn't work for you :)*

Comment: The problem was the size of the image. I thought the size of the image wouldn't matter, that he would look for it anyway

Answer (score 0):

I set the window to open at a preset size, so I took all the prints I needed.

I checked to see if I was finding all the images, and I was finding them just right. But now I put it to run on Mac, to open the window with the same size, however, it doesn't find the images.

I don't know why, but even with the same window size, the image appears smaller on Mac :(

I open a window with the size (1440, 900) and took 2 pictures of the Login button. 1 picture in Mac and the other in Windows.

The size of the pictures:

- Mac = (207, 53)
- Windows = (253, 73)